# What is $cov(X_j - \bar X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Assume $X$ is a p-dimensional i.i.d. vector from $N_p(0, \Sigma)$.

If $X_j$ and $\bar X$ were independent it would be $\Sigma + \frac \Sigma n$ but I think they're dependent and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. from $N(0,\Sigma)$ and $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. You should clarify this in your original statement.

\begin{align}
Cov(X_j-\bar{X})
&= E (X_j-\bar{X})(X_j-\bar{X})^\top
\\
&= E X_j X_j^\top - E X_j \bar{X}^\top - E \bar{X} X_j^\top + E \bar{X} \bar{X}^\top.
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
E X_j X_j^\top &= \Sigma
\\
E X_j \bar{X}^\top
= E \bar{X} X_j^\top
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_j X_i^\top = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma
\\
E \bar{X} \bar{X}^\top &= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j^\top = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma
\end{align}

Comment: What happens if they i.i.d. but from $N(\mu, \Sigma)$?